# When I Add a custom cell after the last index it will replace the last element of a current cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here I have section headers when I click the select button of the section header it will expand and give a multiple products array (count varies) and a fixed cell with a button to call a function on the last of the current dynamic cell when it's expanded.

my table view delegates as follows

```
extension SubstituteItemsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.archivedProducts.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if !self.hiddenSections.contains(section){
            return 0
        }
        return self.newDoublePros[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.row == newDoublePros[indexPath.section].count - 1 {
            
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoSubCell", for: indexPath) as? NoSubCell else {
                fatalError("Nosub Cell not found!")
            }
            cell.doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.submitSub(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubItemsListCell", for: indexPath) as? SubItemsListCell else {
            fatalError("subitems Cell not found!")
        }
     
        let product = self.newDoublePros[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.discriptionLabel.text = product.title ?? ""
        cell.priceLabel.text = "AED \(String(format: "%.2f", product.price ?? 0.00))"
        cell.pk = product.pk

return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   
self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SubHeader") as? SubHeader else {
            fatalError("No Header Found")
        }
       
        header.selectBtn.tag = section
        header.selectBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let product = self.archivedProducts[section]
                self.sectionIndex = [section]
                print("Section Index : \(sectionIndex)")
                header.titleLabel.text = product.title ?? ""
    
    return header
    }

 func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        if self.newDoublePros.count > 0{
        for row in 0..<self.newDoublePros[self.btnTag].count {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row,
                                        section: self.btnTag))
        }
        }
        return indexPaths
    }


    @objc
        private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
            let section = sender.tag
            print("sec tag : \(section)")
            self.btnTag = section
            
            if !self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
                self.getUpcFromEachCell(sectionIndex: section)
                group.notify(queue: .main){
                 print("Request Completed")
                    if self.newDoublePros[section].count != 0{
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                       
                       
                        self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
                        self.tableView.insertRows(at: self.indexPathsForSection(),
                                         with: .fade)
                     
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

                self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: self.indexPathsForSection(),
                                          with: .fade)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                }
            }
        }
```

But the problem is If I have 2 cells (products) in the clicked cell I will get the first 2 products and it will show my fixed NoSubCell after 1 cell. so the last items from the products are missing. When I get only 1 product over there it will show only the fixed cell.

[image]
According to my method, there is 1 more item is missing from the products after a red line in this picture

Can Anyone help me with the code to crack this?

Comment: Not sure if I get it right but if `return self.newDoublePros[section].count` is the number of products and you want to add an extra cell for the fixed one you might wanna return `self.newDoublePros[section].count + 1` and use `if indexPath.row == newDoublePros[indexPath.section].count` to check if the last cell is currently being displayed. this is not a clean approach IMHO but might fix the problem

Comment: @DanielMarx I understood the same. Please, add an answer so you can get rewarded. Before I do :)

Comment: @DanielMarx when I add + 1 to section count app is crashing.. 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section

Comment: I tried with if indexPath.row == newDoublePros[indexPath.section].count but not working

Comment: that's why I said `not a clean approach` tableView can be a pain in the a.. when messing around with indexes. Let me have a second look

Comment: @DanielMarx Yes because when I check without - 1 it shows the correct count of ProductList Cell but not showing the NosubCell after it

Comment: you `indexPathsForSection` func also uses self.newDoublePros.count this means it will return e.g. 2 for 2 products. this will result in a crash when adding these cells. The func tells the tableView to insert 2 cells but in numberOfRows you will return 3 (because of the +1) therefore it will throw an exception. You might wanna consider refactoring your datasource (maybe using a ViewModel) which will return you products + a generic item for the fixedCell so the returned section array looks like [Product, Product, FixedCell]. There is a bunch of approaches

Comment: @DanielMarx what's the approach when api not have fixed cell-related references only we need to manually add the cell.

Comment: in general you should keep any logic regarding the data out of the UITableView. It shouldn't juggle around with indexes at all and just display what the ViewModel/DataSource provides. so if the api return an array of object I wouldn't blindly forward it to the TableView. Use your DataSource/ViewModel to prepare the data. if you haven't used MVVM architectures yet you might wanna have a look

Comment: first article that pops up: https://medium.com/@abhilash.mathur1891/mvvm-in-ios-swift-aa1448a66fb4